# Which field delimiter can be used when in SELECT... INTO OUTFILE CSV when the fields have different special characters

Tags: mysql, csv, google-bigquery, export-to-csv, parquet

I want to export the MySQL data from a table into a CSV file using SELECT... INTO OUTFILE command. The rows contain different special characters like comma(,) semicolon(;) and even have tab spaces in some columns which makes the column values not exported to its corresponding columns

Sample query that I executed,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/outfile.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I have to import these data into BigQuery in a similar table. There are some fields whose values have (;) in a column. When I am using the field separator as (;) it separates the single column value into two values. The same applies for '\t' as well

I also have no idea what kind of special characters these table data will contain

Kindly suggest any of the following ways:

1. Which delimiter would be used to separate fields that doesn't affect the original data
2. Is there any other format like parquet can be supported in MySQL OUTFILE command

Comment: MySQL will automatically enquire string values and escape quotes if necessary. No special configuration or options is required.

Comment: What software are you using to read the CSV files? MySQL uses backslashes to escape special characters but not all CSV software (like Excel) supports it, so you need to export using Excel-compatible double-double-quotes.

Comment: Fields enclosed by parameter is what you are looking for

Comment: I have to import these data into BigQuery, so those column values that contain (;)  is separated into two different column values. That is the issue here

Comment: @Shadow No, Im looking for the appropriate FIELDS TERMINATED BY delimiter that doesn't affect any column values

Comment: We cannot help you with that, since we do not know what values there can be within your fields. A text field can theoratically have any characters that you set as delimiter. There is no universal answer to this question, you need to find the separator that works for you.

Comment: No, select into outfile can only produce a csv file, no other format is supported.

Comment: Why is your escaped by \" instead of simply \ ?

Comment: Unversal (but filesize/diskspace expensive) method is in exporting `HEX(fieldname)` value instead of single `field` for the fields which may contain indefinite special chars. And revert during importing (`UNHEX(value)`).

Comment: @Akina it is only universal to those systems that support both of these functions and these functions can be applied in the export and import process :)

Comment: @Shadow Any DBMS and programming language have functions which can convert HEX codes into bytes and back, it seems.

Comment: @Akina yeah, just many of those can only handle a single entity, not an entire string and in case of dbms not many can do such transformations as part of the import process. If you have to write custom code, the solution is hardly universal.

Comment: *If you have to write custom code, the solution is hardly universal.* This is the fate of any serialization when the source data goes beyond the acceptable limits.

Comment: I completely agree! If you have complex data, you probably need a proper ETL solution. Particulerly if you are not willing to use easy options, such as enclosed by :)

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried SELECT * FROM table_name INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/outfile.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '\"'  ENCLOSED BY '"'
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'; and then setting " as the quote character in BigQuery?

Comment: yes, but that dosen't help

Comment: That should solve your problem. If possible, can you share a sample of the file generated by the command I sent you?